# Using named function declaration instead of anonymous function in Elm

Tags: elm

In the REPL, if I use

```
> String.filter (\char -> char /= '-') "800-555-1234"
```

I get the result:

```
"8005551234" : String
```

as expected.

But if instead of the anonymous function I use a named function declaration like this:

```
> String.filter (isKeepable char = char /= '-') "800-555-1234"
```

I get this error:

```
-- SYNTAX PROBLEM -------------------------------------------- repl-temp-000.elm

The = operator is reserved for defining variables. Maybe you want == instead? Or
maybe you are defining a variable, but there is whitespace before it?

3|   String.filter (isKeepable char = char /= '-') "800-555-1234"
                                    ^
Maybe <http://elm-lang.org/docs/syntax> can help you figure it out.
```

This seems odd to me, since the function declaration itself is an expression that returns a function object:

```
> isKeepable char = char /= '-'
<function> : Char -> Bool
```

So why can't that function reference be passed to `filter` like any expression that evaluates to a function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Named function declarations are only valid at the top level or in a `let` clause. Try this instead:

```
> let isKeepable char = char /= '-' in String.filter isKeepable "800-555-1234"
```